# How to filter id that doesn't equl to list?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I just want to filter User model which id doesn't equal to list of int.

u = User.query.filter(User.id != [1, 2, 3, 4]).all() .. or something?

Answer (score 0):

You can use either [`~in_`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.operators.ColumnOperators.in_) or [`notin_`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.operators.ColumnOperators.notin_).

So:

```
u = User.query.filter(User.id.notin_([1, 2, 3, 4])).all()
```

It would be a great idea to spend some time getting more familiar with SQLAlchemy Docs, a lot of these simple operators are available and well documented.

Answer (score 0):

Better to use [notin_](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.operators.ColumnOperators.notin_) method of [ColumnOperators](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.operators.ColumnOperators)

```
u = User.query.filter(User.id.notin_([1, 2, 3, 4])).all()
```